# 2 Questions regarding XTR105

Tags: current, amplifier

The questions that I'm about to ask will likely "paint very broad a stroke" and open-ended, so feel freed to give whatever that may come to your mind, in full detail or with some rough ideas.

[XTR105 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr105.pdf)

---

See the picture attached and please try to answer:

Q1: What's the purpose of component 1?
Q2: What's the purpose of component 2?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The circled op-amp controls the loop current by controlling the base of the transistor Q1 or 'component 2'.

For example, if Vin = 0, the 100uA current source causes a 97.5mV voltage across the 975\$\Omega\$ resistor, which causes a 4mA output current ( 1 + 975/25 = 40). Similarly, if Vin > 0, then Io = 4mA + Vin(40/Rg).

The circled transistor does the same thing as Q1- controls the output current. If Q1 is present then it carries little current and Q1 takes over. If Q1 is absent the circuit will still function.

However, in loop-powered instrumentation the loop voltage can be quite high, so the power dissipation at full scale (30mA is possible) can also be quite high, so it's frequently desirable to offload that power dissipation into an external component that can handle the dissipation rather than have it on the same die as sensitive circuitry and may not be capable of the dissipation).

Comment: Than you Mr.Pefhany, your reply has been most helpful. If I may, could you please tell me how exactly the linearization process work (related pinout: Vlin)? I can't seem to read anything out other than a negative-feedback loop.

Comment: It's positive feedback that is required. It changes the parabolic-like nonlinearity to an S-shaped, so you can zero the error at three points rather than two. Exactly how it works- you have to look at the math.